# How to implement forEach() in JSX - React Native for Custom Headers

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, jsx

I am trying to create a method that returns a JSON object for custom headers to use with HTTPS requests. This should be defined as customHeaders={{headerKey: 'headerValue'}}
I am new to JSX and a little confused with my implementation of forEach loop here.

Here, this.props.httpHeaders passes a list of Keys and Values. The key is this.props.headerKey and corresponding value this.props.headerValue
The expected return is an Object that holds the key value pairs as {headerKey: 'headerValue'}

Here's my not so correct implementation. Can anyone explain me how to implement forEach() here? Thanks

```js
 getCustomHeaders = () => {
        var customHeaders;
        let keyValueStr = "";
        if (this.isStatusAvailable(this.props.httpHeader) && this.isStatusAvailable(this.props.restURL)) {
            // Building Custom Headers input string
      this.props.httpHeader?.items?.forEach((element) => {
        const attrKey = this.props.headerKey.get(element);
        const attrValue = this.props.headerValue.get(element);
        if (keyValueStr !== "") {
          keyValueStr = keyValueStr.concat(",");
        }
        keyValueStr = keyValueStr+attrKey.value+": "+"'"+attrValue.value+"'";
      });
        }
        customHeaders = JSON.parse("{" + keyValueStr + "}");
        return customHeaders;
    };
```

Comment: Hello! Can you provide a log of your headerKey, httpHeader and the headerValue prop?

Comment: Please add `this.props.httpHeader.items` 's log in question.